# Nested custom theorems using amsthm

Tags: theorems, amsthm, nesting

I am having trouble nesting custom theorem environments in such a way that the inner environment does not inherit the characteristics (e.g. HEADFONT, etc.) of the outer environment.

Possibly the reason is that I hacked a numbered paragraph environment where the numbering is in parentheses.  The parentheses seem to persist in the inner environment.

EXAMPLE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\newtheoremstyle{parag}
  {\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
  {\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
  {}    % BODYFONT
  {}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
  {\bfseries(} % HEADFONT
  {)}         % HEADPUNCT
  { } % HEADSPACE
  {}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC
\theoremstyle{parag}
\newtheorem{pp}[defn]{}    


\begin{document}
\section{Products}

\begin{defn}
    A definition outside the numbered paragraph.
\end{defn}

\begin{pp}
    This is a numbered paragraph
    \begin{defn}
        A definition inside a paragraph has leading open parentheses
    \end{defn}
\end{pp}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why exactly do you want to nest theorems? If the offending opening parenthesis was gone, what would notify a reader that theorem 1.3 is an "inner" environment?

Comment: Theorem environments are not supposed to nested, at least with `amsthm`; you can try `ntheorem`.

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to define `pp` in another way (doing it by hand is not difficult, and you can ask here on TeX.SE if you have problems;).)  Basically, you shouldn't need much more than `\newcounter`, `\arabic` and `\refstepcounter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll just have to re-define the theorem styles yourself. `amsthm.sty` bypasses its own user interface for the three pre-defined styles plain, definition and remark, so it won't explicitly clear many of the variables.